# Gridview Item transitions

Tags: gridview, windows-runtime, transition

Is there any way I could assign a transition to a Gridview's items instead of the entire gridview, somehow like [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269351/WinRT-Transitions-Creating-Fast-and-Fluid-Metro-UI)? I can't seem to manage this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your transitions under GridView/ItemsPanel/ItemsPanelTemplate/WrapGrid/ChildrenTransitions/TransitionCollection.